# Removing multiple parts of string with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I have code that looks like this:

```
<div class="priceCell">
$0.07&nbsp;/&nbsp;ea&nbsp;
</div>
```

I need the code to look like this instead:

```
<div class="priceCell">
$0.07&nbsp;ea&nbsp;
</div>
```

Essentially I'm needing to remove:

```
/&nbsp;
```

Here's my most current attempt within jQuery. This removes the initial "/" but not the non-breaking space:

```
    $("#shopcart-page #content .shopcart-accordion-container #shopcartList .priceCell").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'),"").replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;");
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What do you need regex for? A string replacement should be good enough `my_string.replace( '/&nbsp;', '' )`

Comment: Quite frankly, `$0.07&nbsp;ea&nbsp;` makes no sense. Wouldn't you want `$0.07/ea&nbsp;` so that it reads well?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah... that makes more sense to me as well. This is unfortunately for a client and the clients gets what the client wants in this case (LOL)

Comment: It seems utterly silly to fix this with jQuery every single time a web page is loaded though. Why is the source text not fixed instead?

Comment: It's behind some backend code that would be changed universally (poor design)

Comment: So did my first comment not work for you? It seems like regex is not even needed

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is where I'm at: https://jsfiddle.net/5zjb4aec/1/

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/dj13o7am/

Comment: Hmm, yeah it works there but no in the function above

Comment: Working Fix - Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/6mtqxa9h/2/

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a single replace:

```js
$("#shopcart-page #content .shopcart-accordion-container #shopcartList .priceCell").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\/&nbsp;/g, '');
});
```